# Is it possible to compress PDFs with Ghostscript and keep cross references intact?

Tags: pdf, ghostscript, cross-reference

I have since quite some time used the following batch file (or similar ones) to compress my pdfs.

```
C:\"Program Files"\gs\gs9.26\bin\gswin64 -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dDownsampleColorImages=true -dColorImageResolution=400 -dDownsampleGrayImages=true -dGrayImageResolution=400 -dDownsampleMonoImages=true -dMonoImageResolution=400 -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sOutputFile=FalterinLenzkirchV2_Compressed.pdf FalterInLenzkirchV2.pdf
```

This gives in my case 70% reduction in the PDF but the cross references are gone.

Since the last (?) update of Ghostscript this does not maintain cross references. I have made these cross references in Oxygen/DocBook e.g. from the index to the indexed site. These references appear in the uncompressed PDF, but no longer in the compressed one. Is there an option in Ghostscript to maintain the cross references?

Comment: I reverted from ghostscript 9.26 to 9.20 and the crossreferences are in the compressed file.

Comment: This is good to hear! You should post this comment as an answer since it its definitely helpful!

Answer (score 0):

By reverting to ghostscript version as old as 9.20 I have back the crossreferences.

There is also a much larger compression as in version 9.26 or 9.27 which I tested, too: from 850 MB to 35 MB with 9.20 und to 108 MB with 9.26 or 9.27. The only thing I changed to the batchfile was the directory of the gswin64 file 9.20, 9.26 or 9.27.

Answer (score 0):

The following GhostScript option worked for me:

```
-dPrinted=false
```

This was posted [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/245801/local-hyperlinks-broken-after-pdf-processing-with-ghostscript).